# What are the (unadvertised) Delphi XE2 Starter Edition limitations (if any)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Embarcadero isn't clear on the differences of the XE2 Starter Edition limitations on the order page.

I have a license for Delphi 2007 Pro and I'm looking to move to XE2 because of Unicode and 64-bit compiling. Can I do this with XE2 Starter Edition?

Can I also add 3rd party components?

Are there any big limitations on this edition (except the license terms)?

Comment: The main limitations are, from my POV: 1) Some basic IDE features missing (like Ctrl+Alt+C or full code navigation); 2) Lack of source code of the VCL; 3) The profit limitation itself.

Comment: You don't get 64 bit in the starter edition, but you can add any third party component that doesn't rely on something that isn't in the starter edition, which in my short survey, is about all non-db-centric components.  With DB-centric components, you might find fewer support it.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that what you've read before about the limitations wasn't true, or that the limitations aren't real?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy I never saw anything about Unicode. And they don't tell 64-bit is not in the starter but they state that 64-bit is a reason to upgrade to Pro+... I was just confused thus my question.

Comment: Um, OK. I'm not sure that putting *true* in quotation marks really makes that much clearer, though.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy Heheh you are probably right and reedited my question. BTW, the links RRUZ posted really help sorts this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: Does the starter edition include the 64 bit compiler?

In the starter edition Unicode is suported but the 64 bits compiler is not available.

Q: Can I also add 3rd party components?

From [Delphi XE2 Starter Edition and C++Builder XE2 Starter Edition FAQs](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter-faq)

> **Can I add additional commercial and open source tools and VCL components to Delphi XE2 Starter or C++Builder XE2 Starter?**
>
> In general, yes. However, the Starter editions don't include some
>   features that are available in the higher editions like dbExpress.
>   Since dbExpress functionality isn't included in the product, you
>   wouldn't be able to add something like third party dbExpress drivers.
>   Delphi XE2 Starter and C++Builder XE2 Starter don't have restrictions
>   on adding components like the old Turbo Explorer products did. See the
>   Delphi Feature Matrix or C++Builder Feature Matrix for more
>   information.

Q: What are the true limitations of this IDE?

To check the differences between versions check the [feature matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/delphi-feature-matrix.pdf)

Comment: At least some of the main suppliers of 3rd party components do not support the Starter edition, IIRC. Best to check with the vendor.